# How can I disable syntax highlighting in SublimeREPL, without setting syntax to plain text?

Tags: syntax, highlight, sublimerepl

When I run a program in SublimeREPL, I often get highlighted backslashes '' which show up in pink.

I can work around it, but it's annoying and It would be great if I could disable it. I read on other posts that you can convert the syntax to plain text, but I like having colored words so would prefer not to do that. I just want to remove the pink highlighting.

[Screenshot of SublimeREPL with syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D58JM.png)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeREPL > Settings - User

(If your 'Settings - User' is empty, first copy in the contents of 'Settings - Default')

under "repl_view_settings": add:

this is the first option: first option is without syntax highlighting all in white color.

```
// standard sublime view settings that will be overwritten on each repl view
// this has to be customized as a whole dictionary 
    "repl_view_settings": {
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "auto_indent": false,
    "smart_indent": false,
    "spell_check": false,
    "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "auto_complete": true,
    "line_numbers": false,
    "gutter": false,
    "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
},
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Ik2.png)

this is the second option: second option is based on unix syntax highlighting.

```
// standard sublime view settings that will be overwritten on each repl view
// this has to be customized as a whole dictionary 
    "repl_view_settings": {
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "auto_indent": false,
    "smart_indent": false,
    "spell_check": false,
    "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "auto_complete": true,
    "line_numbers": false,
    "gutter": false,
    "syntax": "Packages/ShellScript/Shell-Unix-Generic.tmLanguage"
},
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqq2e.png)